# Connect to Chromecast Ultra, Ethernet connected to Wireless Router, using devices that are connected to a different Wireless Access Points?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

> Connect to Chromecast Ultra, Ethernet connected to Wireless Router, using devices that are connected to a different Wireless Access Points?

I've installed a **Chromecast Ultra** to my television using Ethernet. The **Chromecast** is connected through RJ45 Ethernet cable to **Switch**, which is connected to the **Wireless Router** that serves as gateway to the Internet.

Using my **Laptop** or **Smartphone**, which are connected to different **Wireless Access Points**, the **Chromecast Ultra** doesn't show up in supported apps. Only when connecting the devices to the **Wireless Router**, does the **Chromecast** show up.

How can I make the **Laptop** and **Smartphone** see the **Chromecast**? Connecting to the **Wireless Router** is not always on option...

My network setup is as follows:

[image]

Comment: As long as everything connects to the same network and has the same IP configuration, it should work just fine. So I would say that your image should work. If it isn't working, please add what isn't working.